# Pytorch 2.0.1+cu118 is not working with Cuda 12.1

Tags: pytorch, version, compatibility

I have CUDA 12.1 installed on my computer, and Pytorch 2.0.1+cu118 installed.

I am trying to the installation of [CLIP-FIELDS](https://github.com/notmahi/clip-fields). When I install gridencoder "python setup.py install", it appears the following error:

```
The detected CUDA version (12.1) mismatches the version that was used to compile
PyTorch (11.8). Please make sure to use the same CUDA versions.
```

I saw on official pytorch forums https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/install-pytorch-with-cuda-12-1/174294 that cuda 12.1 is compatible with Torch 2.0.1+cu118.

Does anyone know the reason of crashing then?

Comment: It literally says in the error message in your question. You must had a CUDA 11.8 runtime available. And what you linked to doesn’t say what you think it does

Answer (score 2):

To match the version of CUDA and Pytorch is usually a pain in the mass.
I see 2 solutions  :

- Install CUDA 11.8 natively. This can be painful and break other python installs, and in the worst case also the graphical visualization in the computer
- Create a Docker Container with the proper version of pytorch and CUDA. This can be painful to learn the first time, but then is a skill that can be used for any later install of a git repository. And there is no risk to compromise the main CUDA of the computer.

Comment: I will try the Docker option, thanks! Do you have any tutorial link to do so? If not I'll search myself it's okey.

Comment: Some useful links: https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html#docker   https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/  And all the varsions to match pytorch-cuda-docker: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/pytorch-release-notes/rel-23-04.html

Comment: And another question. Can a docker container be debugged? Because I want to try (https://github.com/notmahi/clip-fields) and creare my own dataset, and I would like to debug while coding, but if i built a docker container I can't debug right?

Comment: Yes. You build a docker container for pytorch and other requirements. Only once. Then you mount the folder of clip-finds as an external volume with `-v`. and you can many times update the code, commit, pull, push.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when installing flash_attn. I found the release package in the release package list that was consistent with my torch version, python version, and cuda version. Finally, I used pip to install it successfully.

```
pip install https://github.com/Dao-AILab/flash-attention/releases/download/v2.3.6/flash_attn-2.3.6+cu118torch2.1cxx11abiTRUE-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I use cuda 11.8,torch 2.1.1,python 3.10

===============================

The fundamental problem is that the cuda used by the torch version does not match the cuda used by itself.

use python see the torch version:

```
import torch 
print(torch.__version__) # '2.1.1' 
print(torch.version.cuda) # 12.1
```

Reinstall the torch,ok

Comment: The method I mentioned above does not solve the fundamental problem. The fundamental problem is that the cuda used by the torch version does not match the cuda used by itself.

Comment: import torch
print(torch.__version__)  # '2.1.1'
print(torch.version.cuda)  # 12.1

Comment: reinstall torch,  Install the version matching your cuda from the pytorch website